# Open File Explorer when downloading a file

Tags: html, angular

In some machines, there are browser settings that download all files to the /downloads directory by default.
Is it possible to force the file explorer to open when the user downloads the file so he can choose the saving location in these cases?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Web applications do not have access to browser settings due to obvious security reasons. It has be changed in the host system directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

A website cannot override the preference to save to the Downloads folder (neither on a per download basis nor by altering the settings remotely).